# Removing files from remote machine

Tags: bash, ssh, wildcards, rm, remote

I remove files with wildcard by

```
rm /home/files/*.csv
```

but when I try run the command on a remote machine via ssh as

```
ssh user@ip 'rm /home/files/*.csv'
```

it tries to delete `*.csv` file instead, and I get the error

```
rm: cannot remove '/home/files/*.csv': No such file or directory
```

What is the correct syntax to send `rm` wildcard over `ssh`?

Both machines have Ubuntu 20.04 and the standard programs (bash, ssh, etc).

Comment: Are you sure the .csv files are in `/home/files` - not somewhere like `/home/yourusername/files`?

Comment: Are there any csv files in the remote?

Comment: It's likely that there are no filenames matching the pattern. In that case, your shell leaves the pattern unexpanded and tries to call `rm` with that as its argument. Please check whether the files that you are trying to remove are actually there.

Comment: You're all right! The error occurs when there is no file matching the wildcard. If someone posts it as an answer, an accepted answer may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the correct syntax. It's likely that there are no filenames matching the pattern (in fact, this [was confirmed in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647489/removing-files-from-remote-machine/647529#comment1213709_647489)). In that case, your shell leaves the pattern unexpanded and tries to call `rm` with that as its argument.

You would have had the same issue without the use of `ssh` locally:

```
$ rm /tmp/wont*match
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/wont*match': No such file or directory
```

---

Tangential discussion:

Some shells, like the `zsh` shell by default, treats an unmatched globbing pattern as an error, which means that it won't even run the command if a pattern doesn't match anything:

```
$ rm /tmp/wont*match
zsh: no matches found: /tmp/wont*match
```

The `bash` shell can be made to operate in the same way using its `failglob` shell option.  In the following example, `rm` is never invoked:

```
$ shopt -s failglob
$ rm /tmp/wont*match
bash: no match: /tmp/wont*match
```

You could use that in your `ssh` call like so:

```bsh
ssh user@ip 'bash -O failglob -c "rm /home/files/*.csv"'
```

You could obviously use `rm -f` to silence the diagnostic message about not being able to find the filename that you're trying to remove (if that is what you are actually asking about), but that would also mask any exit status from `rm` *in case you want to make sure that the command actually removed something*.

Answer (score 1):

You can silence `rm` with its `-f` flag, which tells it not to worry about deleting files it can't find

```
ssh user@ip 'rm -f home/files/*.csv'
```